# Is it possible to connect an mdb database to a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I wanted to join the database of our bio metrics to the database of our timetrex somehow the databases are both different the other one is MS Access and the other  is MySQL. Is it possible and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Access as a frontend for mysql: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-access-linked-tables.html

This could be helpful too: http://www.montana.edu/web/tutorials/odbc.html

Comment: I always receive an error while testing the connection of mysql Lost connection to mysql server at 'reading initial communication packet',system error:0

Comment: Check your firewall setting on the server and on any firewalls between you (the access file) and the MySQL server. TCP port 3306 should be open (to the server from your host).

Comment: is it still possible to connect even if it is postgreSQL?

Comment: Sorry for asking again, but is it possible to sync the tables of the two databases? for example some of the data from the department table of ms access will also be saved in the department table of PostgreSQL. Thank you for answering my questions.

Comment: This thing is called: ETL (Extract-Transform-Load). I don't know if Access can or can not handle this automatically. Do some web search research ;)